# Angular.js getElementById() not working in $scope function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

el = document.getElementById(id); is not working when inside the below function...the el is null. In the browser debug I can pull up the element with the same code. I am new to Angular.js. Can I not use regular javascript in a function attached to the scope?

```
myappApp.controller('Scroller', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
    $scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
    el = document.getElementById(id);
    }
```

Comment: document.getElementById doenst work cause the dom is maybe not loaded when the script is executed. Thats why the function retuns nothing. Anyway: There is no use in doing that. When you wanna change the element you can use directives from angular or bind the element to an angular-model. Accessing the element in the controller is bad practice and rarely/never needed. Just tell us what you wanna do and we may help you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think DOM is not loaded yet. So please make sure getElementById() run after DOM is loaded completely. If you fail after the 'load' event fires, this is resulted from another cause.

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="sample">
    <h1 id="foo">bar</h1>
</body>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('sample', function($scope){

        addEventListener('load', load, false);

        function load(){
            var el = document.getElementById("foo");
            alert(el);
        }

    });
```