# Can't update variable in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I'm building a Ionic application with angular.js, I'm almost done, but now I have a minor trouble.

In my `templates/menu.html` I have:

```
<ion-item nav-clear menu-close ng-click="filterByPeriod(weekBegin, currentDate)">Filter  </ion-item>
```

and my controller.js:

```
.controller('Home', ['$scope', '$ionicModal', '$cordovaGeolocation', function($scope, $ionicModal, $cordovaGeolocation) {
  App = {
    init: function() {
      setTimeout(function(){
        $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
      }, 200);
    },
  };
  $scope.addMarkersToMap = function(reports, map) {
    var newCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(reports[0].latitude, reports[0].longitude);

    map.setCenter(newCenter);
    map.setZoom(12);
  }

  $scope.filterByPeriod = function(beginDate, endDate) {
    var cityId = window.localStorage.getItem('cityId');

    serviceReports.getDenunciasFromPeriod(cityId, beginDate, endDate)
    .success(function(reports){
      $scope.addMarkersToMap(reports.dados, $scope.map);
    });
  }
  App.init();
}]);
```

I already try do this with a `$scope.apply(function(){}) that encapsulates this method but with both ways I'm catching this error:

http://cl.ly/image/200O1d2F1C46

Anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: The error message indicates that `map` inside `$scope.addMarkersToMap()` is undefined/null. Double check that you are providing an actual object to that function call.

Comment: Can you share how you set your mapOptions ?

Answer (score 0):

$scope.map is not defined.  It might be that you didn't get anything from the google map library or it hasn't populate the data yet.  You might want to use a promise to then use the variable or disable the button until the data is there.

Answer (score 0):

Your map object is not initialized correctly. I suspect your document.getElementById("map-canvas") which  should not work correctly in a controller : DOM manipulation is not synchronized with the angular digest cycle.

Prefer using a directive, you can look how I did it :

https://github.com/bennekrouf/ng-formation/blob/master/app-directives/app/app.js

Comment: Hey @benek, I think not, once this same method (addMarkersToMap) works previously, but when the filterByPeriod is called I catch this error.

Comment: That's it... it works sometimes and sometimes not. It is really not a good practices to manipulate DOM in a controller, because when the controller is executed, it is frequent that the DOM is not completly loaded. That's why we use directive for manipulating DOM. You can hack this mecanism like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049904/angular-js-getelementbyid-not-working-in-scope-function